# checkboxes display is in for loop, how to get getElementById in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Below is the code from innerhtml, dispalyed in a grid view. I need to uncheck other checkbox when one checked from a same row:

```
for(var i = 0; i < optionsArray.length; i++){
    HTML += "<tr>"+ 
            "<td class=tdhead verificationTable width=40% align=left>"+optionsArray[i]+"</td>"+ 
            "<td width=20%>"+
                "<input type=checkbox name=text value="+optionsArray[i]+" id="+i+" onclick=checkbox(this);></input>"+       
            "</td>"+
            "<td width=20%>"+
                "<input type=checkbox name=text value=somevalue id="+i+"/>"+                                
            "</td>"+
            "</tr>";
}

function checkbox(obj){
    var id = obj.id;
    if (obj.checked == true)
    {
        document.getElementById(what/how to mention other id here).checked = false;
    }

}
```

How i can get other checkbox id for document.getElementById in javascript, as it takes a string?
Please help!

Comment: Relations between checkboxes in a way, that one checkbox is unchecked, if another is checked, should be better handled with radio buttons, unless there is a very good reason not to. Nevertheless, other checkboxes in the same row, as your question states, can be selected easily if you can identify the row, that contains the checkbox as well.

Comment: Thanks Jo Oko. If it is aradio button, name is different for each row like, name1, name2...etc. How to get radion button name in getElementsByName() as it takes a string parameter?

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. ids cannot start with an integer. So you need to append something before it like: `id_`
2. Ids need to be unique. You are assigning the same id to multiple checkboxes.

You can use classes for this in combination with the `querySelectorAll`.

```js
HTML = "";
optionsArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (var i = 0; i < optionsArray.length; i++) {
  HTML += "<tr>" +
    "<td class=tdhead verificationTable width=40% align=left>" + optionsArray[i] + "</td>" +
    "<td width=20%>" +
    "<input type=checkbox name=text value=" + optionsArray[i] + " id='id_" + i + "' onclick=checkbox(this);></input>" +
    "</td>" +
    "<td width=20%>" +
    "<input type=checkbox name=text value=somevalue class='row_" + i + "' />" +
    "</td>" +
    "</tr>";
}
document.querySelector("table").innerHTML = HTML;


function checkbox(obj) {
  var boolValue;
  obj.checked == true ? boolValue = true : boolValue = false;

  Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("input.row_" + obj.getAttribute("id").substr(3)), function(elem) {
      elem.checked = boolValue;
    }

  );
}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

The script below takes your script and adjusts the problems.
The main checkbox per row gets an id. While the others get a class name to which the number corresponds with the id of the main checkbox.

The when you click on the main checkbox the function get executed.

It then uses `document.querySelectorAll()` to select the proper checkboxes using the integer from the id. The querySelector returns a node list (a kind of array, but not precisely). We use the map function of the Array object to iterate over all the checkboxes with the `row_#` class name.

We apply a true or false to the checkbox (referred to with `elem`) based upon the main checkbox in that row.

Comment: I am using document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = HTML to display table. Can i use Array.prototype and querySelector if i use document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = HTML ?

Comment: Yes you can. It works selecting classes starting at the root.

Comment: querySelectorAll is not working in our code, please provide alliterative for this. Instead of checkoxes, we can use radio buttons also(except that no two radio buttons/check boxes are selected in one row). If i use radios, how to do document.getElementsByName(), as it takes string

Answer (score 0):

```
        HTML += "<tr>"+ 
                        "<td class=tdhead verificationTable width=35% align=left>"+resStr[0]+"</td>"+   
                        "<td width=10%>"+
                            "<input type=checkbox name='name_"+i+"' value='"+resStr[1]+"' id=id1_"+i+" onclick=checkbox1(this);></input>"+  
                        "</td>"+
                        "<td width=20%>"+
                            "<input type=checkbox name='name_"+i+"' value='"+resStr[2]+"' id=id2_"+i+" onclick=checkbox2(this);></input>"+                      
                        "</td>";
    function checkbox1(obj){
         var otherId = "id2_"+obj.getAttribute("id").substr(4);
         if(obj.checked && document.getElementById(otherId).checked){
             document.getElementById(otherId).checked = false;
         }
    }
    function checkbox2(obj){
         var otherId = "id1_"+obj.getAttribute("id").substr(4);
         if(obj.checked && document.getElementById(otherId).checked){
             document.getElementById(otherId).checked = false;
         }
    }
function updateMemoText(length){
    var memoText = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        var name = "name_"+i.toString();
        if(document.getElementsByName(name)[0].checked ){
            memoText.push(document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value);
        }else if(document.getElementsByName(name)[1].checked){
            memoText.push(document.getElementsByName(name)[1].value);
        }
    }
alert('memoText::'+memoText);
}
```

This is how i am getting selected checkbox value in updateMemoText function, and when one checkbox is selected deselecting the other one in same row using document.getElementById(otherId).checked = false; in checkbox JS function.